# crontab process stdout view

Tags: python, linux, process, cron

I have a python program that has to run on two different linux servers but with a specific order (first on serv1, then on serv2).

I want to automate the process so that I trigger only once the program and that will automatically run on the other server.. I was thinking of creating a crontab on serv2 when program finishes on serv1.

For example, after finished running on serv1, ssh to the other server and create a crontab that will run the program on serv2 in 5 minutes. Problem is I want to be able to see the console output of the program.

I know I can't take control of the program since it wont be a process that my shell instance started and I'm fine with that, I only want the output.. I tried using `tail -f /proc/$proc_id/fd/1` but it showed nothing, while the program was printing.. Is there a way then? Or other suggestions besides using crontab? Installing new programs is not an option since i don't have such rights.

Comment: where proc id ? import os; os.getpid() . Additional create lock file (so mean contained your app pid )

Comment: I know the proc_id and the way to get it in python ;)
Tailing that proc id doesn't seem to work though :/

Comment: if your app got log output, can trace, otherwise returned NONE !